# Link to app on Facebook "Sorry, this page isn't available"

Tags: ios, facebook-apps

I have a native mobile iOs app, that shares updates on Facebook. This all works.

When a user shares something through the app, you get the following in the Facebook news feed:

User X shared a link via My iOS App.

You can then click on the "My iOS App which tries to open a URL like "https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=XXX"

That URL shows the error "Sorry, this page isn't available". On the Facebook developer page I see "This app is live" so I'm wondering why the URL isn't working.

Is there some extra action I need to take?

Answer (score 1):

Select "App Info" on the left side when you are in developers.facebook.com, as shown below

[image: facebook app settings],

and then fill in your app details, and click the button "Create New Page", as shown in the second diagram below

[image: facebook app details page].

This will lead you to the setting up of an app community page for your app. Once completed, select the new page as the app page, and save. The "via" link will go to this page.

Comment: @jorre, you might wonder how it works, because "create new page" creates a page of the form www.facebook.com/page/xx , but it seems that fb redirects https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=XXX to it

Answer (score 0):

check Sandbox Mode should be turn "off"

Answer (score 0):

Have you submitted your app page for review? Go to Edit App -> App Details (left side) -> Submit App Detail Page

Answer (score 0):

Enter your App Store App ID in the settings of your Facebook app. Otherwise, Facebook can't find the app on the device to open it.