# Facebook app profile page not found

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've a android app where users share updates on Facebook. When a user shares something through the app, user gets the following in the Facebook news feed:

User shared a link via "My App".

when you then click on "My App" it opens up a page with the following message.

> Sorry, this page isn't available. The link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed.

Is there some extra configuration i need to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure **Canvas URL** and **Secure Canvas URL**, and make your Facebook App public in order to eliminate this issue.

Comment: Hey @Raptor, can you explain me where can i configure this Canvas URL ad Secure Canvas URL ?

Comment: thank you @Raptor. I've followed steps provided in this link and it worked. thank you again.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296981/link-to-app-on-facebook-sorry-this-page-isnt-available